# Session array variable, form checks, and comparison of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
<html>
        <body>
<form method="post" >
    <h1> name</h1>
    <input type=text name="excel">
    </br>

    <input type=submit name="submit">

    </form><?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['people'] = array();
$var='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

$var=$_POST['excel'];

    if (in_array($var, $_SESSION['people']))
  {
  echo "Already Exists.";
  }
else
  {
   array_push($_SESSION['people'],$var);
}
print_r($_SESSION['people']);

}
else
{
    session_destroy();
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i accept the names of people and want to store it in an array. If a name is repeated then it must not be again added to the session array. Successive name entries must be added at the end of the session array.

I want the output as

```
Array ( [0] => Glenn)  // when first form entry is Glenn. 
Array ( [0] => Glenn [1] => Maggi) //when next form entry is Maggi.
```

Already exists. Add another name. // when the names Glenn or Maggi are entered again in the form field.

Comment: If you want to store multiple values in a variable use "Arrays". In your case `$_SESSION['people']` should be array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always setting `$_SESSION['people'] = array();`. That will empty the session value on every submit. Add a check -

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['people'])) { // Check if the array is not set (for the first time)
    $_SESSION['people'] = array(); // Initialize the session value with empty array
}
```

And always try to add `session_start()` at the start of the page.